# How can I make dynamic Ajax requests with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm creating a social network site using Laravel. I have a page that load all the posts created by users the currentUser follows. I have a comment section on each post. I want a user to be able to comment on any post without the page reloading so the user doesn't have to re-scroll through the page.

I have everything working fine without ajax (minus the reloading page). I'm able to post comments, the page reloads and the new comment is displayed. However, when I try to use Ajax I've been running into problems.

Here is my code.

Here is the **view** of the `comment-box`. It contains a section where I loop through each comment and display them. At the end is the type field so a user can post a new comment:

```
<div class="comment-box-container ajax-refresh">
  <div class="comment-box">
    @if ($type->comments)
      @foreach ($type->comments as $comment)

        <div class="user-comment-box">

          <div class="user-comment">
            <p class="comment">
<!-- starts off with users name in blue followed by their comment-->
              <span class="tag-user"><a href="{{ route('profile', $comment->owner->id) }}">{{ $comment->owner->first_name }}&nbsp;{{ $comment->owner->last_name }}</a>&nbsp;</span>{{ $comment->body }}
            </p>
<!-- Show when the user posted comments-->
          <div class="com-details">
            <div class="com-time-container">
              &nbsp;{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }} ·
            </div>
          </div>

        </div><!--user-comment end-->
      </div><!--user-comment-box end-->
    @endforeach
  @endif

<!--type box-->
  <div class="type-comment">
    <div class="type-box">
    {{ Form::open(['data-remote', 'route' => ['commentPost', $id], 'class' => 'comments_create-form']) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('user_id', $currentUser->id) }}
        {{ Form::hidden($idType, $id) }}
        {{--{{ Form::hidden('user_id', $currentUser->id) }}--}}
        {{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' =>'type-box d-light-solid-bg', 'placeholder' => 'Write a comment...', 'rows' => '1']) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
    </div><!--type-box end-->
  </div><!--type-comment-->


</div><!--comment-box end-->
```

The user submit the form for the comment type box by pressing the "enter/return" key. Here is the **JS** for that

```
<script>
    $('.comments_create-form').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is my **Ajax**

```
(function(){

$('form[data-remote]').on('submit', function(e){
    var form = $(this);
    var method = form.find('input[name="_method"]').val() || 'POST';
    var url = form.prop('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            var tmp = $('<div>');
            tmp.html(data);
            $('.ajax-refresh').html(tmp.find('.ajax-refresh').html());
            $('.type-box').html(tmp.find('.type-box').html());
            tmp.destroy();
            }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
})();
```

I'm running into a few problems with this code. The comment gets displayed on ever single post until I manually refresh the page then it only shows on the correct post. I feel like every post's `comment-box` will need it's own unique `ID` to solve this, but I do not know how to do this with Laravel and make the JavaScript work.

also,

After I submit one comment I can no longer submit a second one because my "submit on enter/return key" functionally is no longer working. My cursor just moves to a new line, and I'm not able to post another comment.

Does anyone know a way to fix these problems?

**EDIT**

Here is my ajax so far

```
(function(){

$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-remote]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this)
    var target = form.closest('div.ajax-refresh');
    var method = form.find('input[name="_method"]').val() || 'POST';
    var url = form.prop('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            var tmp = $('<div>');
            tmp.html(data);
            target.html( tmp.find('.ajax-refresh').html() );
            target.find('.type-box').html( tmp.find('.type-box').html() );
            tmp.destroy();
            }
    });
});
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following to fix the issue:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-remote]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this),
    var target = form.closest('div.ajax-refresh');
    var method = form.find('in......
    ......

    .....
            tmp.html(data);
            target.html( tmp.find('.ajax-refresh').html() );
            target.find('.type-box').html( tmp.find('.type-box').html() );
            tmp.destroy();
            }
    });
});
```

The variable `target` will help you target just the right div to add the ajax response to.

Further, you would have to just reset the relevant form rather than replace the form markup. Otherwise each form will work only once.

**UPDATE**

The above code has been updated to use a delegated `submit` event -- `$(document).on('submit', '.selector', ...)` instead of `$('.selector').on('submit', .....)` since the form content is being replaced after each comment.

**UPDATE 2**

The following delegated `keydown` event should enable you to submit by pressing the enter key:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.comments_create-form', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works for posting the comment and displaying on the correct post. However, I still loose my "press enter/return to submit comment" functionality after I post a comment. I'm not able to post another. I have to manually refresh the page in order to post another comment. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting the same problem. Everything works great except I'm not able to submit a second comment. My "return/enter key" moves my cursor to a new line instead of submitting the form.

Comment: also when the comment is posted it hides all other comments in the comment box that were there previously

Comment: Please post any other JS relevant to submitting the form. Also post a sample of the response returned by Ajax. I'll need those two to adjust my answer.

Comment: What I have in my question is all the JS. Not sure what you mean by sample of the response (Im very new at javascript) Whats happening is I start fresh on the page. I post a comment. The comment appears where it needs to be without the page reloading. If I try to post a comment on the same post it does not work. Im unable to post when I press enter/return key, and my cursor just moves to a new line in the text field. 

However I'm able to post a comment on a different post. but Im noticing now that it is displaying what ever is within the the `ajax-refresh` div closest to the top of the page.

Comment: Update 2 should fix form submission via enter key. ...... If inside the `success` callback of the ajax call you put `console.log( data )` the output will show you what the ajax call returns. I just need to see how that looks like to determine what you mean by ***it hides all other comments in the comment box .....***.

Comment: the console shows that its returning the entire page... i must be doing somehting wrong?  http://postimg.org/image/dec9y6rb5/  and http://s11.postimg.org/465iq8mub/console2.png

Comment: I've posted a new question regarding this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798240/ajax-is-not-returning-the-correct-response-laravel

Comment: If you're getting the entire page back, then you want to concentrate your effort on the Laravel method you're that's receiving the comments, putting them in the database and returning the response. Adjust it to only return what you need.