# Ajax is not returning the correct response. Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm creating a social network site using Laravel. I have a page that load all the posts created by users the currentUser follows. I have a comment section on each post. I'm using ajax to post the comments.

Here is my code.

Here is the **view** of the `comment-box`. It contains a section where I loop through each comment and display them. At the end is the type field so a user can post a new comment:

```
<div class="comment-box-container ajax-refresh">
  <div class="comment-box">
    @if ($type->comments)
      @foreach ($type->comments as $comment)

        <div class="user-comment-box">

          <div class="user-comment">
            <p class="comment">
<!-- starts off with users name in blue followed by their comment-->
              <span class="tag-user"><a href="{{ route('profile', $comment->owner->id) }}">{{ $comment->owner->first_name }}&nbsp;{{ $comment->owner->last_name }}</a>&nbsp;</span>{{ $comment->body }}
            </p>
<!-- Show when the user posted comments-->
          <div class="com-details">
            <div class="com-time-container">
              &nbsp;{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }} ·
            </div>
          </div>

        </div><!--user-comment end-->
      </div><!--user-comment-box end-->
    @endforeach
  @endif

<!--type box-->
  <div class="type-comment">
    <div class="type-box">
    {{ Form::open(['data-remote', 'route' => ['commentPost', $id], 'class' => 'comments_create-form']) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('user_id', $currentUser->id) }}
        {{ Form::hidden($idType, $id) }}
        {{--{{ Form::hidden('user_id', $currentUser->id) }}--}}
        {{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' =>'type-box d-light-solid-bg', 'placeholder' => 'Write a comment...', 'rows' => '1']) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
    </div><!--type-box end-->
  </div><!--type-comment-->


</div><!--comment-box end-->
```

The user submit the form for the comment type box by pressing the "enter/return" key. Here is the **JS** for that

```
<script>
    $(document).on('keydown', '.comments_create-form', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is my **Ajax**

```
(function(){

$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-remote]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this)
    var target = form.closest('div.ajax-refresh');
    var method = form.find('input[name="_method"]').val() || 'POST';
    var url = form.prop('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            var tmp = $('<div>');
            tmp.html(data);
            target.html( tmp.find('.ajax-refresh').html() );
            target.find('.type-box').html( tmp.find('.type-box').html() );
            tmp.destroy();
            }
    });
});
})();
```

When I post a comment on the first post it all works fine. However, when I post a comment on the second, third, fourth etc it only displays the comments from the first post. I have to manually refresh the page, then the correct comments will display.

I'll try to illustrate this problem with images.

Starting fresh, I can easily submit 2 comments on POST 1
http://s27.postimg.org/6ej76hunn/comment1.jpg

When I scroll down to Post 2, I see it already has a comment, I will submit a new comment
http://s23.postimg.org/x65ui2ryz/comment_2.jpg

HERE'S THE PROBLEM: When I submit the comment on POST 2, the comments that were in POST 2 disappears, and are replaced by the comments from POST 1.
http://s30.postimg.org/ugl08oz01/comment_3.jpg

The back end still worked, because when I reload the page everything is the way it should be
http://s9.postimg.org/w51fgyzen/comment_4.jpg

When I check the console Ajax is returning the entire page.

I'm completely stuck. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Here is my controller that is loading the page with the posts:

```
public function index()
    {
        // load posts into the view.
        $posts = $this->postRepository->getFeedForUser(Auth::user());
        return View::make('newsfeed', compact('posts'));
    }
```

The `getFeedForUser()` is this:

```
public function getFeedForUser(User $user)
    {
        // get a list of all the ids the user follows
        $userIds = $user->followedUsers()->lists('followed_id');
        // add in the current users posts as well
        $userIds[] = $user->id;
        // Resource is the posts
        return Resource::with('messages', 'media', 'user', 'videos', 'comments', 'locations')->whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->latest()->get();
    }
```

That `Resource` model has the relationship for the comments. It looks like this:

```
class Resource extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Duuer\Comments\Comment');
    }   
}
```

The route for saving a comment to the DB looks like this:

```
Route::post('post/{id}/comment', ['as' => 'commentPost', 'uses' => 'CommentsController@postComment']);
```

The `CommentsController` looks like this:

```
class CommentsController extends \BaseController {

use CommanderTrait;
/**
 * Leave a new comment
 * @return Response
 */
 public function postComment()
 {
     extract(Input::only('user_id', 'resource_id', 'body'));
     $this->execute(new PostCommentCommand($user_id, $resource_id, $body));

     return Redirect::back();
 }
public function deleteComment()
{
    $comment = new Comment;
    $user = Auth::user();
    $id = Input::only('id');
    $comment->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('id', $id)->first()->delete();
    return Redirect::back();
}
}
```

I'm using a command bus, so my handler class looks like this:

```
public function handle($command)
    {
        $comment = $this->postRepository->leaveComment($command->user_id, $command->resource_id, $command->body);

        return $comment;
    }
```

That `leaveComment()` method looks like this:

```
public function leaveComment($user_id, $resource_id, $body)
    {
        $comment = Comment::leavePostComment($resource_id, $body);

        User::findOrFail($user_id)->comments()->save($comment);

        return $comment;
    }
```

The `leavePostComment()` method in the Comment model looks like this:

```
public static function leavePostComment($resource_id, $body)
    {
        return new static([
            'resource_id' => $resource_id,
            'body' => $body
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must submit the form but bind the keydown event on the input/textarea (better IMHO for you JS).

For your AJAX request, I recommand to get only a JSON, with Laravel, you can use `if(Request::ajax())` and return only JSON instead of the whole page, then, you have just to append the new messages to the DOM.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? I'm very new to Laravel and even newer to JS. I added in my controllers to my question. How would I add `if(Request::ajax())` to my controller?

Comment: The `if(Request::ajax())` is only needed if you want the same URL for both HTML and JSON requests, but you can also create 2 controller methods, 1 for each. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822213/reading-laravel-json-response-in-jquery-ajax or this good example: http://blog.igeek.info/2013/using-ajax-in-laravel/